# Cannot push into gitolite-admin repo

Tags: ssh, gitolite

When I try to push, gitolite says

```
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 339 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote:         ***** ABORTING *****
remote:         bad username me,
To ssh://git@githost-adm/gitolite-admin
   32cfc9f..41ee58f  master -> master
```

githost-adm described in my ~/.ssh/config as

```
Host githost-adm
HostName real.hostname.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitolite-admin
```

Private keys are loaded in ssh-agent, so this enables ssh to use specific identity key when i want to connect to gitolite-admin repo.  There is similar ssh alias githost-as-me containing another identity file for connecting to other repos.

sshd log seems to prove that pubkey was accepted

```
Accepted publickey for git from real.hostname.ip port 38916 ssh2
```

So it’s probably somewhere inside of gitolite where the error hides.

Comment: It is OS user name who has both keys to gitolite-admin and to the others repos. Gitolite user created for accessing gitolite-admin repo called ‘gitolite-adm’, ‘me’ user has no rights to access it and mentioned only in the others repos access list.

Answer (score 0):

This error message comes from [`src/lib/Gitolite/Conf/Store.pm`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Conf/Store.pm#L90-L97):

```
sub parse_users {
    my $users = shift;
    my @users = split ' ', $users;
    do { _die "bad username '$_'" unless $_ =~ $USERNAME_PATT }
      for @users;

    return @users;
}
```

With:

```
$USERNAME_PATT        =  qr(^\@?[0-9a-zA-Z][-0-9a-zA-Z._\@+]*$);
```

Called by [`src/lib/Gitolite/Conf.pm`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Conf.pm#L43-L80) when storing the new users from your config file that you are pushing in the `gitolite-admin` repo.

```
} elsif ( $line =~ /^(-|C|R|RW\+?(?:C?D?|D?C?)M?) (.* )?= (.+)/ ) {
            my $perm  = $1;
            my @refs  = parse_refs( $2 || '' );
            my @users = parse_users($3);
```

So double check your config file syntax (here, as [documented for Gitolite V3, or 'g3'](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/admin.html#conf): if your are still in V2, check [this page](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2/exbac.html)).
There must be some kind of syntax error in it.

Anyway, **this isn't an ssh issue**.